# Two manim animations not displaying at the same time

Tags: manim

I have a sample of code that goes like this:

```
class IntroToEquation(Scene):
def construct(self):
    equation = MathTex(
        "2^x=3",
        substrings_to_isolate="x",
        font_size=144
    )
    equation.set_color_by_tex("x", YELLOW)

    self.play(FadeIn(equation))
    self.wait(2)
    self.play(equation.animate.to_edge(UP, buff=0.5), equation.animate.scale(0.75))
    self.wait(1)
```

and the third self.play() contains two things that should be going at the same time, but only the scaling is played in the final video. From everything that I've looked at this should be working. Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way animations are handled in Manim, you cannot have two different animations on the same object at the same time. But you can make a composite animation by stacking the individual transformations:

```
class IntroToEquation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        equation = MathTex(
            "2^x=3",
            substrings_to_isolate="x",
            font_size=144
        )
        equation.set_color_by_tex("x", YELLOW)

        self.play(FadeIn(equation))
        self.wait(2)
        self.play(equation.animate.to_edge(UP, buff=0.5).scale(0.75))
        self.wait(1)
```

[image]

[Come over to Discord](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim) if you want to learn more tips and tricks